# Visual Studio ReportViewer Designer Version

Tags: winforms, rdlc, reportviewer, visual-studio-2017

I'm moving my old project to Visual Studio 2017 [from 2015], but whenever I try to edit a RDLC report in VS it updates my report version and makes it incompatible with 'Microsoft.ReportViewer.WinForms' version 10.0 using 12.0.

The thing here is that I need to keep the version, because every user has the v10.0 DLL aside the project so I could not update everyone at once.

I tried to embedded that DLL into the executable but it says this:

> Cannot embed interop types from assembly
>   'Microsoft.ReportViewer.WinForms, Version=12.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=89845dcd8080cc91' because it is missing the 'Guid'
>   attribute

Any help or workaround would be appreciated, thanks in advice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone wondering how to do this, I didn't found a workaround.

Instead I decided to upgrade to latest `ReportViewer` version `[10.0 -> 14.0]` as it has **retrocompatibility**, it can read older reports and I don't have to upgrade them.

In other hand for the fact that I have several user installations with the DLL in the same folder of the executable, I have an automatic tool which allows me to update any assembly without much effort. This tool is made by me, so I can't tell how to do it other way.